# Stuck at the Welcome Screen, is it possible to stop a Windows login?

Tags: windows-7, redirection

Is it possible to stop a Windows 7 login when you're stuck at the welcome screen due to a large file in a profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pull the network cable; your cached credentials will get you in, as long as it's not the first time on that PC. If it is, you don't have much of a choice. Don't let it save back to disk on logout, either; that'll just make it even worse.

Then get that junk out of the roaming profile ASAP.